# Printing spaces to align numbers according to my pyramid pattern

Tags: java, algorithm

It sounds a lot easier than it looks. Basically I have my code finished this is my output where the leading number is whatever integer the program receives as input. In this case n = 5:

```
    1
   21
  321
 4321
54321
```

but this is what it is suppose to look like:

```
        1
      2 1
    3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

How should I go about adding spaces in between my numbers while maintaining this pattern? I've tried editing here and there but it keeps coming out like this:

```
    1
   2 1
  3 2 1
 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

#### My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayPattern {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter an integer and I will display a pattern for you: ");
      int n = input.nextInt();
      displayPattern(n);
   }

   public static void displayPattern(int n) {
      final int MAX_ROWS = n;
      for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++) { 
         for (int space = (n - 1); space >= row; space--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
         }

         for (int number = row; number >= 1; number--) {
            System.out.print(number + " "); /*<--- Here is the edit.*/
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

Edit:
@weston asked me to display what my code looks like with the second attempt. It wasn't a large change really. All i did was add a space after the print statement of the number. I'll edit the code above to reflect this. Since it seems that might be closer to my result I'll start from there and continue racking my brain about it.

Comment: You are closer with your second attempt, so post that code instead.

Comment: I added working code example.

Comment: Do mark whichever answer you found helpful as 'Accepted'.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the program working, however this only caters to single digit number (i.e. up to 9).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Play
{
    public static class DisplayPattern
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter an integer and I will display a pattern for you: ");
            int n = input.nextInt();

            displayPattern(n);
        }

        public static void displayPattern(int n)
        {
            final int MAX_ROWS = n;
            final int MAX_COLUMNS = n + (n-1);
            String output = "";

            for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
            {
                // Reset string for next row printing
                output = "";

                for (int space = MAX_COLUMNS; space > (row+1); space--) {
                    output = output + " ";
                }

                for (int number = row; number >= 1; number--) {
                    output = output + " " + number;
                }

                // Prints up to n (ignore trailing spaces)
                output = output.substring(output.length() - MAX_COLUMNS);
                System.out.println(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Works for all `n`.

In `i`th row print `(n-1 - i) * length(n)`  spaces, then print `i+1` numbers, so it ends with 1 separated with `length(n)` spaces.

```
public static void printPiramide(int n) {
    int N = String.valueOf(n).length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = i+1; j > 0; j--) {
            int M = String.valueOf(j).length();
            for (int k = 0; k < (N - M)/2; k++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(j);
            for (int k = (N - M)/2; k < N +1; k++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DisplayPattern{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer and I will display a pattern for you: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        List<Integer> indentList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int maxLength= totalSpace(n) + (n-1);

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
            int eachDigitSize = totalSpace(i);
            int indent = maxLength - (eachDigitSize+i-1);
            indentList.add(indent);
        }

        for(int row = 1; row<=n; row++){
            int indentation = indentList.get(row-1);

            for(int space=indentation; space>=0; space--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for(int number = row; number > 0; number--){
                System.out.print(number + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
      }
}

    private static int totalSpace(int n) {

           int MAX_ROWS = n;
           int count = 0;

           for(int i = MAX_ROWS; i >= 1; i--){
              int currNum = i;
              int digit;
              while(currNum > 0){
                digit=currNum % 10;

                   if(digit>=0){
                      count++;
                      currNum = currNum/10;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
      }
}
```

It works properly for **any number of rows(n)**.

Answer (score 0):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) solution to the problem:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, MAX)
            .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, MAX)
                    .map(j -> MAX - j)
                    .mapToObj(k -> k == 1 ? k + "\n" : k <= i ? k + " " : "  ")
                    .forEach(System.out::print)
            );
```

Output for `MAX = 5`:

```
        1
      2 1
    3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score -1):

For the bottom row, you have the right number of spaces. But for the next row from the bottom, you're missing one space on the left (the 4 is out of line by 1 space). In the next row up, you're missing two spaces on the left (the 3 is out of line by 2 spaces)... and so on.

You're adding a number of spaces to the beginning of each line, but you're only taking into account the number of digits you're printing. However, you also need to take into account the number of spaces you're printing in the previous lines.

Once you get that part working, you might also consider what happens when you start to reach double-digit numbers and how that impacts the number of spaces. What you really want to do is pad the strings on the left so that they are all the same length as the longest line. You might check out the [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)%20String.format()) method to do this.